# A probability (exactly k out of n)

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

Suppose that I know that 18%  of a population is willing to pay more taxes.

When I select random 48 people from that population, what is the probability that *exactly* 8 of them are willing to pay more taxes? 1?

Comment: $\binom{48}{8}\times 0.18^{8}\times 0.82^{40}\approx 0.148$

Comment: It depends on the size of the population. If the population is 100 people, then there are 18 exactly that are willing to pay more in taxes. The probability of choosing exactly 8 from 48 that are willing to pay more is $$\dfrac{\dbinom{18}{8}\dbinom{82}{40}}{\dbinom{100}{48}} \approx 19.5\%$$ But, for populations that are very large compared to the sample size, Loobear's answer is close.

Comment: thanks @Loobear for your solution, but what about this argument. If the sample is random I will expect 18%*48 $\approx$ 8 people who in the sample of 48 who are willing to pay more taxes. The probability to find 8 people in that sample will exactly 1.

Comment: That is nonsense: if you throw 6 dice you're not always throwing a $1$ because $6 \times \frac16 = 1$.. The expected value (!) is $0,18 \times 48$ yes, over many experiments like this.

Comment: @ InterstellarProbe, Way should the size of the population matter  in this case? The size of the population is unknown

Comment: You're drawing from a "vase" without replacement. If the population is small relative to the sample this will matter. In this case I think you're supposed to ignore it.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma, thanks for pointing out the nonsense. The expected value (word of the day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binomial distribution formula tells us this is

$$\binom{48}{8}\left(\frac{18}{100}\right)^8 \left(\frac{82}{100}\right)^{40}$$

Comment: I'm indeed considering the size of the total population to be very much larger than $48$ so this approximation is very good, normally.